# Listbox with object as images

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listbox

I want to display my objects form observablecollection as images with labels. Object contains name, and image path as a string. My problem is that this images aren't in solution. I created something like this but it shows object in rows and without images. I want to show them in boxes.

I edited my source code:

```
<ListBox Name="lb_drinki" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="650" Width="1254" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyImagesItemTemplate}"/> 
...

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyImagesItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding imgpath}" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding name}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: well, seems like you're binding to names only ... so why would you expect something different?

Comment: This seems more likely to work. Can you please verify that the paths you have are valid?. I'm assuming you can easily verify that the names show properly so that each control has it's binding properly done?

Comment: My objects contain relative path to images, I think thats a problem. Names display correctly.

Comment: if you are facing trouble with accessing file which isn't part of your solution,please try this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/74f716a1-073f-40c5-a488-c05b42f6067e/how-to-access-external-images-in-wpf-via-c-code?forum=wpf )

Comment: Can you paste a couple of examples of what your likns look like. I'm using relative paths in some project, so it should work

Comment: Most of objects have `images\\drinki\\defaultIMG.jpg`. In other part of aplication I use 
`BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(); img.BeginInit();  img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; img.UriSource = new Uri(zaznaczony.imgpath, UriKind.Relative); img.EndInit();
zdjecie.Source = img;` And I dont have problem with displaing images

Comment: You haven't set your ItemsSource, could you please provide the code for the class containing imgpath&name. And the vm/codebehind you use to populate the list?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I suspect your problem might be your datamodel not implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), or that imgPath and name are **properties**. Or you may have added the images to the project wrong. Ensure they are Resource not copy, or content with if copy never, depening if you want them in the assembly or outside.

This works, I've changed your property names, created a basic viewmodel, with a collection of dataitems as you have described, I think. I've bound your items to this collection.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="LBImage.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:lbImage="clr-namespace:LBImage"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <lbImage:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>               
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyImagesItemTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" MaxHeight="100" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Name}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="650" Width="1254" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
             ItemsSource ="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyImagesItemTemplate}"/>

</Grid>
```

Datamodel, note the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged here. Maybe the Image path should be an URI type instead?

```
public class ModelBase
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class SomeItem : ModelBase
{
    private string name;
    private string imagePath;
    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == name) return;
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public String ImagePath
    {
        get { return imagePath; }
        set
        {
            if (value == imagePath) return;
            imagePath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImagePath");
        }
    }
}
```

And finally your viewmodel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // assuming you have the images
    private ObservableCollection<SomeItem> items = new ObservableCollection<SomeItem>
    {
        new SomeItem{ImagePath = "Images/a.jpg", Name= "sdfgsdfgsdfgdfsg"},
        new SomeItem{ImagePath = "Images/b.jpg", Name= "sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg"},
        new SomeItem{ImagePath = "Images/c.jpg", Name= "sdfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgssdfg"},
    };
    private SomeItem selectedItem;
    public ObservableCollection<SomeItem> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, items)) return;
            items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    public SomeItem SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, selectedItem)) return;
            selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but your code is very complicated for me. I don't know how to program in MVVM. I Tried to implement it in my code but I get unhanded exception System.StackOverflowException. :(

Comment: @GarryMoveOut Works here! I suspect your app is crashing at InitializeComponents? Can you make sure that the proper viewmodel is set and that you haven't mixed any UserControl. with Window. in the xaml?